# NHibernate truncating values when using Restrictions with a "Like"

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a system that uses Fluent NHibernate auto mapping.  I have a string property that is mapped with a length of 3.

```
mapping.Map(x => x.CCY1Code).Length(3);
```

Here is an example of a restriction that I'm building:

```
Restrictions.Like("CCY1Code", "USD", MatchMode.Anywhere);
```

Watching this in SQL Server Profiler, it looks like NHibernate is parameterizing the SQL.  But in doing so it is limiting it to three characters.  But NHibernate is also surrounding my value "USD" with percent signs.  So what should be "%USD%" gets truncated to "%US".  Here are some snippets from SQL Server Profiler:

```
CCY1Code like @p9
@p9 nvarchar(3)
@p9=N'%US'
```

Other than lengthening my field to five characters to work around this, is there any other way to address this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that this is partially a bug.

It is pointless to search with `Like` on a 3 character field when the token itself is 3 characters long. Use an `Equals` instead so you will take advantage of indexes (if any are setup).

You will fall on the bug though when searching for '%US%', but a workaround would be to run the query as:

```
Restrictions.Like("CCY1Code", "US", MatchMode.Start) 
      || Restrictions.Like("CCY1Code", "US", MatchMode.End)
```

It's better because the first part also takes into advantage of Indexes while avoiding truncation

EDIT:
I would just like to add here that this is definitely a bug from NHibernate's part since you can also `Like` using various expressions as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: +1 I think this is a fantastic answer, never thought about it this way before. Are you 100% sure that US% and %US both use the index rather than a table scan? (MsSQl only)

Comment: no i say that only the first part uses indexes. That is the "US%". The other can only default to a table scan but if the first part succeeds it will never run

Comment: Marking this as answered since you confirmed that it is a bug.  I was hoping that I was missing something simple, but I guess not!  I agree that it is usually pointless to do a Like on a 3 character field with a 3 character token.  But in my particular case the user is presented with advanced filtering options.  They can choose "equals" or "like", thus the possibility they will enter 3 characters.